# How to make double quote work with facebook api post

Tags: php

This is getting me crazy I have this code

```
try {
$value = array_map('utf8_encode', $value);
$ret = $fb->POST('/me/feed', $value); 

  // mark topic as posted (ensure that it will be posted only once)
  $sql = 'UPDATE news SET fb_status = 1 WHERE id = ' . $share_topic['topic_id'];
  if($conn->query($sql) === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  }
  $result .= $share_topic['topic_id'] . ' ' . $share_topic['facebook_post'] . ' successfully posted to Facebook!' . $line_break;

} catch(Exception $e) {
  $result .= $share_topic['topic_id'] . ' ' . $share_topic['facebook_post'] . ' FAILED... (' . $e->getMessage() . ')' . $line_break;
}

sleep(3);
```

}
 }

When the post hits the facebook it looks something like this

"some text &quote;some text &quote;" can you help me encode the double quotes? I'm losing my mind...

Comment: Can you post more of the code so we have better context?

Comment: try


$str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

// note that here the quotes aren't converted
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);

Comment: here it is more code, @Jah how can I integrate that in my code, sorry i'm noobie here :P

Comment: how does the **$value** output look before **$value = array_map('utf8_encode', $value);** ?

Comment: @Jah before utf8 it looked like this D�sseldorf

Comment: _“can you help me encode the double quotes?”_ – you need to _decode_ the HTML entities in the content you are sending to Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe can you help with the code to do that? thanks

Comment: when I try to user html entities I have this error Warning: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given